# Error when I have two versions of python: 'version_info' object has no attribute '__version__'

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, anaconda, labview

I was using Python 3.6.5 64 bit with Anaconda that was working for me.
At the moment, I need to connect LabView to Python. As I understood, LabView supports the Python version 3.6 and the bitness of python and LabView have to be same. I have installed LabView 32 bit on my windows (64 bit) as they recommended to install LabView 32 bit even if we have windows 64.

So, I installed Python 3.6.0 32 bit then, by using python shell I made a simple code with importing numpy module and connect it to LabView, I works.
But, when I write a code that needs importing matplotlib, it has the version error in python shell:

```
AttributeError: 'version_info' object has no attribute '__version__'
```

So, I cannot integrate it with LabView.

when I was installing modules (pip, matplotlib and ...), I changed the path to: `"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts>"`
Then wrote: `pip install numpy` and `pip install matplotlib`. There is no error when I install them but when I want to run a simple code by python shell it cannot import matplotlib. I also have tried the old versions of matplotlib by pip install matplotlib==version number, but it didnt solve the problem.
On the other hand every thing is ok in anaconda 64 bit.

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Comment: @john-hen The new version of python works well for me with Anaconda but I have to use the older version of Python to integrate it with LabView (and for integrating with LabView the bitness should be same. So I have to use Python 3.6-32 bit).

Comment: @john-hen Thanks a lot. It solved my problem. I installed Python 3.6.5 32 bit (same as Anaconda that the activated python was 3.6.5 32 bit). After installation I didnt need to install packages one by one by pip; because I had installed them in Anaconda before. Then easily import them to Python shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because there are two versions of python on your computer. When you want to reference to a particular version of python just do: py - version

---

For example, if you want to reference to python 3.10 in cmd, do: py - 310 And when you want to reference to 3.9 do: py - 39

---

To add the bit version add a dash and the bitness
eg: `py -3.9-64`
eg: `py -3.6-32`

---

**Make sure you have the correct spacing^**

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How about the bitness (32 and 64 bit)?

Comment: Because I have Python 3.6.5-64 bit and Python 3.6.0-32 bit.

Comment: @User ah so at the end of `py -3.6` add on -32 so eg `py -3.6-32`

Comment: In cmd and in that specific directory when I write: `py -3.6-32 pip install matplotlib` It says: `python.exe: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` but I have put the **get-pip** file in to that folder and installed it. The problem is that after writing `py -3.6-32 get-pip.py` it uninstall `pip-21.3.1` and install the same thin again. Then by writing `py -3.6-32 pip --version` it says: `C:\Users\Asgari\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe: can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: and by writing `py -m pip --version` it says: `pip 20.2.4 from C:\Users\Asgari\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)`, So, I have another version of python 3.8-64 on anaconda that has not been activated. Anyway, the pip is installed on anaconda. I think this is the main problem. Sorry for my long comment.

Comment: @User ok so you got through?

Comment: I am trying to install pip correctly on this directory `python 3.6-32` in addition to anaconda.

Comment: @User do you have  python and its scripts folder added to path?

Comment: The pip problem is more a separate question

Comment: Yes I have added to the path. But previously, I have set the anaconda path as default. Can it be the problem?

Comment: @User I'm not too sure, I think you should ask another question about this.